# How to declare the unknown number of line from file

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I have to work with a file that can change number of line due to the previous operation(from python script), and that number of line will used to declare the other variable, like this.

```
integer NumberOfLine  !This is not work,Of course.
real(8) F(FixedDimension,NumberOfLine)
integer, parameter :: NewDimension = ANumber*NumberOfLine
```

How can I declare the NumberOfLine properly. Thanks.
I can pass number of line from python, So basicly I know that number after python operation complete

Comment: `real(8)` is bad! http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/fortran/939/data-types/4390/precision-of-floating-point-numbers#t=201608091021532182103

Comment: Thanks!, I just learn to use fortran for a few day, this help a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you declare a parameter, its value must be fixed at compile time. So your `integer, parameter :: newDimension = ANumber * NumberOfLine` cannot work if the compiler doesn't know the value of `NumberOfLine`.

What you can do is use allocatable arrays:

```
program test_alloc

    implicit none
    integer, parameter :: dp = selected_real_kind(p=15)
    real(kind=dp), dimension(:,:), allocatable :: F
    integer :: i
    integer, parameter :: FixedDimension = 10

    print *, "Enter i"
    read(*, *) i

    allocate (a(FixedDimension, i))
    a = i
    print *, a

end program test_alloc
```

Comment: Thanks!, I never write Fortran before, this help a lot

Comment: My original solution was to your question, so I used the `REAL(8)` which you did but really shouldn't. I've now replaced it with a more flexible method of getting 64-bit floating numbers.

Comment: I see, I will try to understand what floating point numbers is.